# ncursesw application won't catch ctrl-C/S/Z

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ncurses, tmux, windows-terminal

I'm trying to create a c++ application using ncursesw.

I want to use some shortcuts for my own functions.

1. Ctrl+C
2. Ctrl+S
3. Ctrl+Z

I know I can just catch the signals directly but apparently a lot of documentation is telling me that this shouldn't be necessary and that ncursesw provides this functionality.
As far as I understood this, you should be able to catch those keycodes by using `raw();` and enabling the `keypad(stdscr, true);` function. But this won't do it for me.

I am somewhat suspicious tho that there may be some other application catching those keys bevor they reach me.
I am running my application inside the following stack:

- NewWindowsTerminal

  - WSL

    - Tmux

      - zsh

        - myapp

Here is the code I use to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

void quit();

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // Init Curses ----------
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    WINDOW* win = initscr();
    atexit(quit);
    raw(); // disable line buffering
    curs_set(0); // hide cursor
    use_default_colors(); // enable transparent black
    start_color(); // enable color
    clear(); // clear screen
    noecho(); // disable echo
    cbreak(); // disable line buffering
    keypad(stdscr, true); // enable function keys
    mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL); // enable mouse events
    
    // the following loop is just test code
    int input;
    do {
        input = getch();
    } while(input != 'q');
    
    return 0;
}

void quit() {
    endwin();
}
```

The goal with this code is to ONLY be able to exit using 'q' and not using Ctrl-C but it still exits using the Ctrl-C.

Does anyone have any idea if somewhat is causing an issue here or if its actually not even possible to catch those keys just by using the curses library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's program has a bug, which prevents it from working as intended:

```
raw(); // disable line buffering
```

is overridden by

```
cbreak(); // disable line buffering
```

(deleting that line, the `getch` will return `^C`, etc.)

Comment: thats actually it makes sence now that I think about it :/ thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In this order:

- Enable the keypad function keys by calling `keypad(stdscr, true)`. Defined in `termios.h`.
- Disable the Ctrl-C signal by calling `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)`.
- Enable the Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-S keys by configuring the terminal using the `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` functions. Defined in `termios.h`.

We can ONLY be able to exit using keystroke 'q' and not using standard terminal exit: Ctrl-C.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void quit() {
    endwin();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // Init Curses ----------
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    WINDOW* win = initscr();
    atexit(quit);
    raw(); // disable line buffering
    curs_set(0); // hide cursor
    use_default_colors(); // enable transparent black
    start_color(); // enable color
    clear(); // clear screen
    noecho(); // disable echo
    cbreak(); // disable line buffering
    keypad(stdscr, true); // enable function keys

    // Disable Ctrl-C signal
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    
    // Enable Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-S keys
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    term.c_cc[VSTOP] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;
    term.c_cc[VSUSP] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);

    int input;
    do {
        input = getch();
        switch(input) {
            case KEY_CTRLC:
                // Ctrl-C pressed
                break;
            case KEY_CTRLZ:
                // Ctrl-Z pressed
                break;
            case KEY_CTRL('s'):
                // Ctrl-S pressed
                break;
        }
    } while(input != 'q');
    
    return 0;
}
```

`unistd.h` is required to access the `STDIN_FILENO` constant, which represents the standard input file descriptor. We pass this constant to `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` functions to modify the terminal settings for the standard input.

Comment: I still had to #include <signal.h> but that works thanks a lot!